# Child Object has parent Object as attribute JPA caused endless JSON

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have the following defined within a parent object CommentTarget:

```
// bi-directional many-to-one association to EmployerDetails
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "commentTarget", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Comment> comments;
```

and this defined within the Child Comment:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH} )
@JoinColumn(name = "comment_target_id")
private CommentTarget commentTarget;
```

However when I take the list from the target and return as a JSON:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/ticketV2")
public class TicketV2Controller {

    @Autowired
    CommentTargetService commentTargetService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{ticketId}/comments", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Comment> getTicketComments(@PathVariable(value="ticketId") String id,
                                    @RequestParam String type){

        CommentTarget commentTarget = commentTargetService.findByTargetIdAndTargetType(Long.valueOf(id), TargetName.valueOf(type));
        List<Comment> commentsList = commentTarget.getComments();

        return commentsList;
    }
```

It craps out as it keeps the reference to the target then the list within it and so on and so on:

```
[
{
    "id": 997,
    "commentedBy": 1,
    "commenterName": "Exchange Admin",
    "comment": "123456",
    "commentTarget": {
        "id": 703,
        "targetId": 216,
        "targetName": "TICKET",
        "created": 1586548428358,
        "updated": 1586548428358,
        "comments": [
            {
                "id": 997,
                "commentedBy": 1,
                "commenterName": "Exchange Admin",
                "comment": "123456",
                "commentTarget": {
                    "id": 703,
                    "targetId": 216,
                    "targetName": "TICKET",
                    "created": 1586548428358,
                    "updated": 1586548428358,
                    "comments": [
                        {
                            "id": 997,
                            "commentedBy": 1,
                            "commenterName": "Exchange Admin",
                            "comment": "123456",
                            "commentTarget": {
                                "id": 703,
                                "targetId": 216,
                                "targetName": "TICKET",
                                "created": 1586548428358,
                                "updated": 1586548428358,
                                "comments": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 997,
                                        "commentedBy": 1,
                                        "commenterName": "Exchange Admin",
                                        "comment": "123456",
                                        "commentTarget": {
                                            "id": 703,
                                            "targetId": 216,
                                            "targetName": "TICKET",
                                            "created": 1586548428358,
                                            "updated": 1586548428358,
                                            "comments": [
```

Not sure how to separate the relationship between the two when just wanting to return the child list of comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that:

1. @JsonManagedReference is the forward part of reference – the one
   that gets serialized normally.
2. @JsonBackReference is the back part
   of reference – it will be omitted from serialization.

Change your mapping like below.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "commentTarget", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Comment> comments;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "comment_target_id")
@JsonBackReference
private CommentTarget commentTarget;
```